# Solving $\iint dx dy $ ,$\{y=x\},\{y=x^2-1\}$

Tags: calculus, integration

> $$\iint dx dy $$
>   I need to find the area between:$$\{y=x\},\{y=x^2-1\}$$

**My attempt:**

$$\int\limits_{y=-1}^{y=1}\bigg[\int\limits_{x=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt5}{2}}^{x=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt5}{2}} dx \bigg]dy$$

> is it correoct so far?

Comment: Maybe it would be easier to evaluate $\int dx\int_{y=x}^{y=x^2-1} + \int dx\int_{y=x^2-1}^{y=x}$ (bounds of integration you have finded)?

Comment: This is not a rectangle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your lower limit for $x$ is correct, but in the upper bound you need to replace the minus sign with a plus sign. Remember the $\pm$ in the quadratic formula?

Since the bounds in the problem are on $y$ in terms of $x$, you should integrate over $y$ first and then over $x$. You can also see from the diagram that if you let $x$ range over the interval, the bounds for $y$ are easy, but if you first let $y$ range over its interval you get two different expressions for the range of $x$.

[image]

When you make that change, the bounds for $y$ are wrong. just take $y$ from the parabola $y=x^2-1$ up to the line $y=x$. So the integral is

$$\int_{x=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt5}{2}}^{x=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt5}{2}} \left[\int_{y=x^2-1}^{y=x}\,dy\right]\,dx$$